# Consecutive smooth triplets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, integers

Consecutive $n$-smooth triplets with no common factors are possible. The sequence 64, 120, 324, 2024, 17576, 248676, 314432, 6571774, 7496644, 116026274, 196512876 isn't in OEIS, but they do appear in Koninck's *Those Fascinating Numbers*. For each of these, $k-1, k, k+1$ all have a rather low maximum prime factor. For consecutive smooth pairs, [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem) can be used. That's how I verified these up to 97-smooth, but that took my current program a week.  Values for 101 and 113 are unverified.

[image: smooth triplets]

If the "no common factors" is dropped, the middle-odd $n$-smooth triples always seem to be higher than the middle-even $n$-smooth triples.

[image: smooth triplets]

Can anyone extend, improve, or correct these results?

Comment: I don't completely understand.  Are you trying to find the largest such triplet for each smoothness bound?  Does "13 of 24" mean that 13 of the 24 primes beneath the smoothness bound were used in the triplet?

Comment: Yes and yes for those questions.

Comment: Hi Ed. What do you mean by, "...the middle-odd $n$-smooth triples always seem to be higher than the middle-even $n$-smooth triples"? Can you give a starting example so we can extrapolate the rest of the pattern?

Comment: For example, 19-smooth triplets, 324 and 2431. 53-smooth triplets, 248676 and 1205645.

Comment: What is the definition of an "-smooth triplet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better result for 113:

```
1129770949: 41 43 53 107 113
1129770950: 2 5 5 7 7 11 11 37 103
1129770951: 3 19 29 67 101 101
```

You can use a fairly simple sieve algorithm to find smallish solutions very quickly if you use a reasonable programming language.  My program finds all primes less than the smoothness bound and computes $v_p = \lfloor 4000 \log_{10}(p) \rfloor$ for each such prime.  If you are looking for solutions in the interval $[L, L+N]$, add up $v_p$ for each small prime divisor of each number in the interval.  Dump out all consecutive triplets such that the sum of relevant $v_p$'s is larger than $\lfloor 4000 \log_{10}(L) \rfloor - 4000$.  Postprocess the results manually to weed out any false positives.

**EDIT**:  I left said sieve running while I was at work today.  For the common-factors case, the following solution may also be interesting:

```
138982582998: 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 7 29 47 97 103
138982582999: 13 31 37 43 43 71 71
138982583000: 2 2 2 5 5 5 23 23 59 61 73
```

Comment: That seems to be a new discovery, I don't see a mention of it on Google.

Comment: Very interesting -- the second discovery seems known, and actually opens up a lot of related research.   http://oeis.org/A003032